# Integrate Twilio ruby class into my main app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, twilio

I have completed writing (and testing) a voice verification service using Twilio independently but am unsure of how to integrate it into my main app. As of now I have 2 files:

> make_call.rb

and

> twiml_messages.rb

Basically, in my main app, I will click a link ("verify my number") and then cause the `make_call.rb` file to be called, which contains the following code:

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'twilio-ruby'

# put your own credentials here - from twilio.com/user/account
account_sid = 'xxyy'
auth_token = 'xxyy'

# set up a client to talk to the Twilio REST API
@client = Twilio::REST::Client.new account_sid, auth_token

@call = @client.account.calls.create(
  :from => '+1123',   # From your Twilio number
  :to => '+1123',     # To any number
  # Fetch instructions from this URL when the call connects
  :url => 'ngrok/verify-phone-call'
)
```

(Have intentionally replaced the key data areas with insignificant values.)

Essentially, should I create a class and put this into a Ruby function and then call the function as part of the object when the url is clicked?

If yes, then what about the next steps..

```
post '/verify-phone-call/:id' do
  content_type "text/xml"
  Twilio::TwiML::Response.new do |r|
    r.Say 'Hi, you requested to verify your phone number'
    r.Gather :numDigits => '1', :action => '/verify-phone-call/handle-gather/:id', :method => 'post' do |g|
      g.Say 'To verify your number, press 1.'
      g.Say 'Press any other key to start over.'
    end
  end.text
end
```

This is in `twiml_messages.rb`, and is called from my `make_call.rb`, via an ngrok connection that exposes the webserver. Should I place this 'post' into a function too?

Comment: Hey @RPV, what is your main application built in? Is it a Rails application?

Comment: Yes, it is a rails application

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

If you're adding this then there's a couple of things you can do.

With the code to start the call you could just move that into the controller action that lies behind the "verify my number" link you talk about. Take a look at this tutorial on [building a "Click to call" application in Rails with Twilio](https://www.twilio.com/docs/tutorials/walkthrough/click-to-call/ruby/rails) that shares a few steps with phone verification. It covers making calls and responding to them with TwiML.

You might also want to check out this blog post by my colleague Carter on how to work with [Twilio on Rails](https://www.twilio.com/blog/2014/02/twilio-on-rails-integrating-twilio-with-your-rails-4-app.html).

Let me know if this helps!